# Can the MMS's content type hub be on a different farm to the MMS?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have a farm in North America and another in South America. We need a local MMS in each farm but would like to share a single content type hub across these services - we'd like to point the MMS on both farms to the North American content type hub.

[image: CTH setting]

Will that work? I assume it depends on whether the service talks to the hub via the object model or via web services.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that the answer is "no".

Some colleagues went through an architecture validation exercise with Microsoft and although I didn't hear a direct answer to this, they proposed that we should replicate the hub. It therefore seems safe to assume that simply pointing to a remote hub is not possible.